# Is it possible to select a column name in a subquery for INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, subquery

Is it possible to SELECT a column name in a subquery for an INSERT?

For example, if I had a table (table1) which maps events to columns in another table (table2):

Table1:

```
+------+--------+---------+
| id   | events | columns |
+------+--------+---------+
|    1 | event1 | column1 |
|    2 | event2 | column2 |
|    3 | event3 | column3 |
|    4 | event4 | column1 |
|    5 | event5 | column2 |
|    6 | event6 | column3 |
+------+--------+---------+
```

Table2:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| id   | column1 | column2 | column3 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
|  ... |     ... |     ... |     ... |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

is there an SQL statement, such as:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
(
    id, 
    (SELECT columns          /* the interesting subquery */
     FROM table1 
     WHERE events='event1')
) 
VALUES (1, 123);
```

that would result in inserting table2 with values:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| id   | column1 | column2 | column3 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1 |     123 |    NULL |    NULL |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: No, you need dynamic sql to do that, and I think that MySql has only limited support for that in the form of [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Can your `columns` column in table1 have unlimited columnnumber, or only 3 ?

Comment: add one more field in Table1 as value which store values that you are trying to store in table2.

Comment: tsabz - limited amount of columns only. Think my problem as a grouping problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use expressions for identifiers. You can do like this:

```
insert into table2 (id, column1, column2, column3)
select 1,
  case columns when 'column1' then 123 else null end,
  case columns when 'column2' then 123 else null end,
  case columns when 'column3' then 123 else null end
from table1
where events = 'event1'
```